# What is wrong in this proof?

Tags: proof-techniques, correctness-proof

I stumbled upon this [wikipage](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/User:Joe) that has got this proof :

[image]

I rechecked [sum rule of differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_rule_in_differentiation).

And i can not understand where is this wrong.

Any Tips ?

I think that the second line

x^2 = x + x +... x times...

being used for differentiation is wrong. but i am not sure .

Comment: This is a math question appropriate for math.stackexchange.

Comment: Here is a simpler "contradiction". Differentiate the first line to obtain $1 = 0$.

Comment: @scaahu but if you differentiate each one w.r.t x it would give 1.

Comment: You need to understand what "Differentiable function" means so you can figure out what the problem is. Yuval is right that this is a math question more suitable on Math SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof states that $(\underbrace{x+x+\dots+x}_{x~ times})' = (\underbrace{1+1+\dots+1}_{x~ times})$. Let's give it a try.

$$\lim _{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\underbrace{x+\epsilon+x+\epsilon+\dots+x+\epsilon}_{x+\epsilon~ times} - \underbrace{x+x+\dots+x}_{x~ times}} {\epsilon} =\\ \lim _{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{ \underbrace{\epsilon+\epsilon+\dots+\epsilon}_{x~ times} + \underbrace{x+\epsilon+x+\epsilon+\dots+x+\epsilon}_{\epsilon~ times}}{\epsilon} = \\ \lim _{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{ \underbrace{\epsilon+\epsilon+\dots+\epsilon}_{x~ times} + \underbrace{x+x++\dots+x}_{\epsilon~ times} + \underbrace{\epsilon+\epsilon+\dots+\epsilon}_{\epsilon~ times}}{\epsilon} =\\
\lim _{\epsilon \to 0}\underbrace{1+1+\dots+1}_{x~ times} + \underbrace{x}_{1 ~time} + \epsilon = 2x$$

Comment: I always thought that if we take (x+x..+x) as f(x) then should it not be `(f(x+h) -f(x))/h` which means it to be x times and not (x+h) times. Any links for this ?

Comment: The length of $\underbrace{x + x + \dots + x}_{x~times}$ depends on x. Pretending that it does not led to the proof you posted. In general, you should find no serious considerations for this as $\underbrace{a+a+\dots+a}_{b~times}$ is only an uncomfortable way to write $ab$ and doesn't make much sense outside of natural numbers.

Comment: @AshishNegi You can say x times only when x is a positive integer.(2.6 times or $\pi$ times does not make sense). $f(x)$ is not continuous if the domain of $f$ is the set of positive integers. $f$ is not differentiable if $f$ is not continuous. You cannot do differentiation if $f$ is not differentiable. Thus, the arguement you saw on that page is invalid.